# Open Firefox on Ubuntu Server accessed via Git Bash SSH on Win7

Tags: ubuntu-server

I am currently trying to open Mozilla Firefox on a Ubuntu Server. I am accessing this server via SSH on the Windows 7 Git Bash. I have installed it and when I run `firefox`, it displays:

> `Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified.`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did u tried  `export DISPLAY=:0.0`?

Comment: Yes, I have. It said: "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0.0"

Comment: See [this](https://jdhao.github.io/2018/03/02/Windows-connect-server-x11-with-gitbash/). It worked for me but with `X11UseLocalhost yes`.